# Calculating Annual Standard Deviation of Daily TRMM Precipitation

Tags: google-earth-engine, function

I am trying to calculate the annual standard deviation of daily data from 3hr TRMM observations at the catchment scale. First, I take a temporal sum of 3hr measurements to get daily P sums. Then I calculate the sum across all pixels in the catchment for all days (exceeds user memory). Lastly, I try to calculate the standard deviation at the annual time scale for each catchment sum. The biggest error I am getting is that `dailySumCatchment.reduce` is not a function. How can I fix this?

Ideally, what I need is one standard deviation value for each catchment for each year from daily sums for each catchment.

```
// Objective: calculate monthly and annual variance from daily precipitation means for 81 basins from 2001 to 2019

var trmm = ee.ImageCollection("TRMM/3B42")
// daily precipitation means
// Define start and end ee.Dates.
var startDate = ee.Date('2001-08-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2019-7-01');
var nDays = ee.Number(endDate.difference(startDate, 'day'));

// TEMPORAL SUM ACROSS HOURS TO DAY
// Map over the list of days to make daily sum composites.
var trmm_day_list = ee.List.sequence(0, nDays.subtract(1)).map(function(n){
  var t1 = startDate.advance(ee.Number(n), 'day');
  var t2 = t1.advance(1, 'day');
  var dailySum = trmm
      .filterDate(t1, t2)
      .select('precipitation')
      .sum();
  return dailySum
    .set({'system:time_start': t1.millis()});
});
//print(trmm_day_list);
var trmm_day = ee.ImageCollection(trmm_day_list) 

// SPATIAL SUM ACROSS PIXELS TO CATCHMENT
// calculate sum across all basin pixels at each time step
var sumOverCatchment = function(x) {
  var sum = x.reduceRegions({
    collection: basins,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    scale: 27830});
  return sum
    .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['sum']))
    .map(function(feature) {
      return feature.set({
          'imgID': x.id(),
          'date': x.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')
      })})};

var dailySumCatchment = trmm_day.map(sumOverCatchment).flatten();
//var dailySumCatchment = ee.ImageCollection(dailySumCatchment)
Map.addLayer(dailySumCatchment);

// TEMPORAL SD ACROSS 365 DAILY CATCHMENT MEANS TO YEAR          
var trmm_annual_list = ee.List.sequence(1, 18).map(function(n) { 
  var t1 = ee.Date('2000-08-01').advance(n, 'year'); 
  var t2 = t1.advance(1, 'year'); 
  var annualStdDevCatchment = dailySumCatchment
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev());
  return annualStdDevCatchment
    .set('system:time_start', t1.millis());
});
print(trmm_annual_list);
// /*
// convert back to image collections
var stdDev_annual = ee.ImageCollection(trmm_annual_list)

//print(trmm_annual);
//Map.addLayer(annualStdDev,{},'Annual');

// calculate area and set geometry to NULL for cleaner table
var myproperties=function(feature){
  var area = feature.geometry().area().divide(1000 * 1000);
  feature=ee.Feature(feature).setGeometry(null);
  return feature.set('AREA', area);
};
var stdDev_annual = stdDev_annual.map(myproperties);

//print(stdDev_annual);

// export and visualize final results
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: stdDev_annual,
    description: 'trmm_variance_annual',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'trmm_variance_annual',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'})
// */
```

Asset link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/sharsid94/all_sheds_81

Comment: Also when I convert dailySumCatchment to an image collection, I get the error "ImageCollection.reduce: Invalid type.
Expected type: Image<unknown bands>.
Actual type: Feature.". Why would it be calling it a feature?

Comment: Because that is what you made it :) Why not create an image collection with annual standard deviation (temporal StD if you like) for each pixel and then for each feature get 1 average StD per year? Or does it need to be a StD with spatial variability inside a feature for each year?